# Create a UserStorageProvider from java code

Tags: realm, keycloak

I want to add a custom *UserStorageSPI to Keycloak*.

We can do it fro UI by selected it from dropdown under *User-Federation -> Add Provider* option, but we wanted to to do it from *Java Code*. We are trying to create an automated system where properties are picked up from *YAML files* and corresponding realms and clients are created automatically.

```java
Keycloak keycloakClient = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                             .serverUrl(authUrl)
                             .realm(StringUtils.defaultString(realm, "master"))     
                             .username(username)
                             .password(password)
                             .clientId(StringUtils.defaultString(client, "admin-cli"))
                             .resteasyClient(client)
                             .build();
    
keycloakClient.realms().create(realm);
```

This is a sample code that we are using to create a realm.
Looking for a similar way to add the UserStorageSPI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need ComponentRepresentation, which you can create with the following code:

```
private ComponentRepresentation createComponentRepresentation() {
    ComponentRepresentation cr = new ComponentRepresentation();
    cr.setName("your user storage provider id");
    cr.setProviderId("your user storage provider id");
    cr.setProviderType("org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProvider");
    cr.setConfig(new MultivaluedHashMap<>());
    cr.getConfig().putSingle("cachePolicy", "DEFAULT");
    cr.getConfig().putSingle("priority", "10");
    cr.getConfig().putSingle("enabled", "true");
    cr.setParentId("your realm id");

    return cr;
}
```

And use keycloak client to create user federation on realm:

```
keycloakClient.realm("your realm id").components().add(createComponentRepresentation());
```